# Usage of Ansible JMESPath in queries

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I am using following JSON file:

*sample.json*:

```json
{
    "lldp_output['gathered']": [
        {
            "mode": "trunk",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "trunk": {
                "encapsulation": "dot1q"
            }
        },
        {
            "access": {
                "vlan": 12
            },
            "mode": "access",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/1"
        },
        {
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    tmpdata: "{{ lookup('file','sample.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Take 4
      debug:
        msg: "{{ tmpdata | community.general.json_query(lldp_output['gathered']) }}"
```

I get the following error:

```
TASK [Take 4] ********************************************************************************************
task path: /root/scripts/atest.yml:18
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'lldp_output' is undefined"
}
```

How do I query the JSON shown so I get a list of all ports that have `mode: trunk`

When I run in a playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Find trunk ports
  hosts: ios

  tasks:
    - name: Collect interface output
      cisco.ios.ios_l2_interfaces:
        config:
        state: gathered
      register:
         "intf_output"

    - debug:
        var=intf_output

    - name: Take 4
      debug:
        msg: "{{ intf_output | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: >-
          "lldp_output['gathered']"[?mode=='trunk']
```

The structure returned is like following:

```json
{
    "intf_output": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "gathered": [
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0"
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/2",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/1",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/2"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/3"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/0"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/1"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/2"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/3"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/0"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/1"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/2"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For each host I run against the playbook against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `json_query` must be a string. Because you haven't quoted your argument, Ansible is looking for a variable named `lldp_output`. But you've got additonal problems, since you're trying to access a key named `lldp_output['gathered']`, but `[` is a syntactically significant character in JSON (and JMESPath queries), so that needs to be escaped as well.

In order to avoid all sorts of quote escaping contortions, we can place the query itself into a variable, so that we have:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    tmpdata: "{{ lookup('file','sample.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Take 4
      debug:
        msg: "{{ tmpdata | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: >-
          "lldp_output['gathered']"
```

Note that we are using the `>-` block quote operator, which means that the value of `query` is the literal string `"lldp_output['gathered']"`, including the outer quotes.

That playbook outputs:

```
TASK [Take 4] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "mode": "trunk",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "trunk": {
                "encapsulation": "dot1q"
            }
        },
        {
            "access": {
                "vlan": 12
            },
            "mode": "access",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/1"
        },
        {
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/2"
        }
    ]
}
```

To get just those systems with `mode` equal to `trunk`, just add that
criteria to your query:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    tmpdata: "{{ lookup('file','sample.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Take 4
      debug:
        msg: "{{ tmpdata | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: >-
          "lldp_output['gathered']"[?mode=='trunk']
```

This will output:

```
TASK [Take 4] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "mode": "trunk",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "trunk": {
                "encapsulation": "dot1q"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Update

Given the data you've shown in your updated question, things are much
simpler, because you don't have the weird quoting you had in the
original question.  With `intf_output` defined as shown, you can
write:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Take 4
      debug:
        msg: "{{ intf_output | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: >-
          gathered[?mode=='trunk']
```

Comment: You have got me further ahead. I need to get only the ports which are trunk ports.  How do I   filter so I only get ports with mode: trunk ? and saved to a variable I can use later on.

Comment: I think something like: msg: "{{ tmpdata | json_query(query) | json_query(?mode=='trunk') }}"  Not so sure of all the escaping

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to further filter the results.

Comment: When I use your solution in script it fails, this is because the output:  is actually per inventory_hostname and not what I had so: ok: [access01] => {
    "intf_output": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "gathered": [.... running the script fails .  Suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: I'm not really clear on the structure of the data you're describing. If you could update your question to include a formatted sample of the data actually looks like I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: I have updated question with output from playbook it is bottom of question, keeping original question as well as I think people will run into both types where they want it to work

Comment: I have accepted your answer.  Just an update it seems output I was using to match changed in cisco.ios.ios_l2_interfaces compared to whatever I was using to query the switch previously.